# Nginx server config, change location block dynamically

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name domain.com;

        root /var/www/html/try;
        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /package/mhshohel5/index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/try$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

Everything ok with above code, i want to just change try_files dynamically, just like

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /package/mhshohel5/index.php?$args;
```

To

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /package/*/index.php?$args;
```

- means changeable directory, is there any way to make it.

Any helps will be appreciable.

Comment: Do you want the location block to try files in all subfolders of `package` or should that depend on a query variable or hostname for instance?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply, I want to load a directory from package which name will be dynamic, i don't know that name. every time it will create directory. directory structure `/package/dont-know-name-of-this-directory/index.php`